# Add body class wordpress error

Tags: php, wordpress

I´m using this code to add class to the body depending on the page:

```
    <?php

    // add a custom body class
    add_action( 'body_class', 'ilwp_add_my_bodyclass');
    function ilwp_add_my_bodyclass( $classes ) {
        if ( is_page( '12' ))
            {
                $classes[] = 'login';
                return $classes;
            }
        else if ( is_page( '9' ))
            {
                $classes[] = 'homepage';
                return $classes;
            }   
    }

    ?>
```

It works when i´m **navigating thru static pages**, but when I go to a single post I get this error:

*Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /Users/diego/Sites/bb/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 389
class="">*

Any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the 'else' statement.
Let the 'return' out of if-else statement.
Maybe you need to do this:

```
<?php add_action( 'body_class', 'ilwp_add_my_bodyclass');
function ilwp_add_my_bodyclass( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page( '12' ))
        {
            $classes[] = 'login';
         }
    else if ( is_page( '9' ))
        {
            $classes[] = 'homepage';
        }   
    return $classes
} ?>
```